# ReactJS component going behind Navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

In my React app, I have a navigation bar on top. I call this Navbar component in App.js as shown below.

```
export default function App() {
   return (
      <Router>
         <Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <section>
               <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                  <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
               </Switch>
            </section>
         </Fragment>
      </Router>
   );
}
```

The problem is that, whenever I hit any of these URLs like '/login', '/dashboard', The component associated with them renders behind the navbar and not below it. While I can add multiple `<br/>` tags below `<Navbar />`to shift these components below, but this does not seem like a good solution as some components already have significant whitespace above them and adding `<br/>` will shift them even further below which I don't want. How to solve this issue? My other components return simple `<div>`. My Navbar is a `<Appbar position='fixed'>` from the **material-ui/core** library.

Comment: Try to add style to your `NavBar` component. It needs to be `display: "flex"; flex: 1;`

Answer (score 2):

The official Material UI documentation covers this specific issue in detail: https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#fixed-placement

If you use Fixed Placement on a Material UI AppBar you will need to offset your content by either including a second empty `<Toolbar />` component below the appbar or by using `theme.mixins.toolbar` CSS.

---

**Solution A using a second `<Toolbar />` component:**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AppBar position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>{/* content */}</Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Toolbar />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

---

**Solution B using `theme.mixins.toolbar`:**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  offset: theme.mixins.toolbar,
}))

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AppBar position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>{/* content */}</Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <div className={classes.offset} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
};
```

---

MUI also suggests using `position="sticky"` instead to avoid this issue; however this is not supported in IE11 so use with caution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because you may have used fixed-top class if using bootstrap or other similar css property. I was also having same issue for below code, after removing fixed-top class its working fine now.